# How to change language in Windows Movie Maker

Tags: windows-movie-maker

Every time I open Windows Movie Maker, it comes up in a foreign language (Swedish?). I've already tried going to Control Panel, and going to Region and Language, and it didn't work.

How do I change Movie Maker's language back to English?

Answer (score 3):

Windows Live Essentials allows you to select the language during the installation, but changing the language afterwards is indeed a well hidden "feature".

In case you have already installed the Swedish version and want to change the language you prefer, you can do it with Language Setting instead of installing the full installer again. Please try the following steps:

1. Search for “langselector” in Windows 7 start menu or Windows 8 start screen, and click on langselector app.  (langselector app is located in the SYSTEM Drive:\Program Files\Windows Live\Installer\ or \Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Installer\ )
2. Click the drop-down arrow, and then click the language that you want to start using.
3. If the language you select isn’t installed yet, make sure you’re connected to the Internet, and then click OK.
4. The Windows Essentials installer will install the new language. This may take a few minutes. When it’s done, click Close.
5. Restart your Windows Essentials apps to see the new language.

Source: http://www.liveside.net/2012/08/08/windows-essentials-2012-how-to-quickly-change-the-language/

Comment: Works on Windows 10 too (I had to choose the second langselector app path)

Answer (score -1):

HOW TO CHANGE PHOTO GALLERY AND MOVIE MAKER`S LANGUAGE IN WINDOWS 7 TO ENGLISH

Hi
1-Open start menu > All programs >look for Photo Gallery.
2-Right click on Photo Gallery >left click on *open file location*.

3-A window will appears and you will see languages folder files ,like English(en),Russian (ru) and others may be,keep English folder(en) 
  and delete other languages folders.
4-Run Photo Gallery and you will see it changed to English.